# Join splitted files and uncompress them same command [LINUX]

Tags: linux, split, tar, compression

I ran a command to split a file of 2TB into files of 50GB each.

...| split -b 50G

Now, I need to join and uncompress them, on the same command. Because I don't have enough free disk space to have them both.

```
To join: cat part-* > big_file.gz

To uncompress: tar -xvf big_file.gz
```

How could I run those commands above on the same line?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that Stackoverflow questions need to be related to programming. Please review the [help/on-topic]. The question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se] but do check their help first before requesting migration there.

Comment: voted to move to unix.stackexchange.com as well, to get a `gz`d file, you need to do `gzip -c part-* > big_file.gz`. If your original file was ziped before you tried spliting it, I don't think it is working the way you intend. Do small tests to see that your ideas are working before spending time and resources on an untested idea. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To run several commands in bash use ; as a separator, like:

cat part-* > big_file.gz;tar -xvf big_file.gz

you can also combine them with some bash loop commands like while, for, etc

Comment: Yes.. but by running the command above, the `big_file.gz;tar` will actually be created... so `big_file.gz;tar` + the uncompressed `big_file.gz;tar` will double my disk size and I don't have enough... I wanna rung the CAT + TAR on the same command, so I won't have two copy of those.. got it?